# How to use an handheld device with GNU/Linux and YouTube to protect from death threats?

Tags: backup, remote, streaming, recording, youtube

Suppose you fear you could meet someone who will threaten you with death.

Assuming the bad guy won't destroy your handheld (for example an Ubuntu Touch device) on sight, a barely decent form of protection would be to have your phone continuously stream its microphone to a remote server you do not have access to, programmed to publicly upload the recorded audio content on a popular YouTube channel on a regular basis, unless a circle of neutral, trusted, physically unavailable people for the threatener do not cancel it if nothing happened.

I want to know how to do that.

Comment: Most unique question I have seen on this board lately. +1 sir.

Comment: As they say, [mater artium necessitas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_is_the_mother_of_invention) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is  simplest procedure I came up with. It will work on any GNU/Linux handheld, but instructions for an Ubuntu touch device are provided, anyway.

### On the handheld device

- **Ubuntu Touch specific:** Increase the size of the `system.img` of your Ubports phone with some extra gigs.
- **Ubuntu Touch specific:** Make your rootfs writable

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

- Proceed to install `tor` and `rsync`; for an Ubuntu Touch device it would be

```
sudo apt install tor rsync
```

- Have this uncommented in your torrc

```
/etc/tor/torrc
----------------
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/ssh/
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

- Start `tor`

```
service tor start     # Ubuntu touch
systemctl enable tor  # Any other Ubuntu version
systemctl start tor   # Any other Ubuntu version
```

- Get the onion address of your handheld

```
/var/lib/tor/ssh/hostname
--------------------------
your_onion_address.onion
```

- Record from microphone with

```
arecord ~/Music/recording.wav
```

### On the remote computer

- Install rsync and [`youtube-video-upload`](https://github.com/remorses/youtube-video-upload) (follow the instructions on the website to configure it for your account).
- Write the `recording.yaml` corresponding to your recording.wav.
- Run the sync_and_upload.sh script

```
sync_and_upload.sh
-------------------------
#!/usr/bin/env bash
watch -n <seconds_between_consecutive_syncs> rsync phablet@your_onion_address.onion /path/to/recording.wav &
watch -n <seconds_between_consecutive_uploads> python3 -m youtube_video_upload /path/to/recording.yaml
```

#### Known issues

- It is not adviced by Ubuntu Touch manual to write on the rootfs, so you will have to repeat the procedure every time you upgrade your phone;
- After receiving a call, microphone mutes in the recording;
- Tor should start at boot;
- In Ubports/Ubuntu Touch everything should run into a libertine container.

Comment: Now, on this site I can admire the solution and try it on my E4.5  ;-)